# Angular 6 ngFor select object on a nested JSON

Tags: json, angular6, ngfor

I am have a hard time trying to do an ngFor on nested JSON. I have read that ngFor is supposed to be for arrays only, but there are so many APIs that pump out nested JSON, that I figure that has to be a way.

The following is an example of the category JSON that I am receiving - I am simplifying what it could be:

```
{
  "Categories": {
    "candles": {
      "name": "Candle"
    },
    "oils": {
      "name": "Oil"
    },
    "chocolates": {
      "name": "Chocolates"
    },
    "toys": {
      "name": "Toys"
    }
  }
}
```

The following is an example of the http get:

```
  this.http.get(this.jsonUriNestObj).subscribe(resultObj => {
  this.categoryObj = resultObj["Categories"];
  console.log(
    "resultObj['Categories']: ",
    JSON.stringify(resultObj["Categories"])
  );
```

This would be an example of what comes back in the console:

```
resultObj['Categories']:  {"candles":{"name":"Candle"},"oils":{"name":"Oil"},"chocolates":{"name":"Chocolates"},"toys":{"name":"Toys"}}
```

The following is what is currently not displaying any options in the select, but at the same time, zero errors and zero warnings:

```
<select id="categories" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Please select an item</option>
  <option
    *ngFor="let item of this.categoryObj.name; let i = index"
    value="{{ i }}"
    >{{ item }}</option
  >
</select>
```

I have tried this.categoryObj[i], this.categoryObj[i]['name'], etc...

How do I ngFor a nested JSON - hopefully, you can offer a dynamic solution.

As usual, thanks in advance and happy new year to you and yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `keyValue` pipe to iterate objects - I think this pipe is available from angular 6.1

Try something like this

```
<select id="categories" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Please select an item</option>
  <option
    *ngFor="let item of this.categoryObj | keyvalue; let i = index"
    value="{{ item.key }}"
    >{{ item.value.name }}</option
  >
</select>
```

I think this might help you - but make sure this `pipe` seems to be `impure`

For more info check [this](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe#keyvaluepipe) - Happy new year and happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over the object not array, array can be iterated easily.

You can use `pipe` to transform your objects to array or you can change your `json` object to `array`.

You need one new variable which can iterate easily and you can use it later, like this

```
 name = 'Angular';
  categoryObj =  {"candles":{"name":"Candle"},"oils":{"name":"Oil"},"chocolates":{"name":"Chocolates"},"toys":{"name":"Toys"}}
  outputData: any;

  constructor(){
    this.outputData = Object.keys(this.categoryObj).reduce((prev,curr)=>{          
      prev.push(this.categoryObj[curr].name);
      return prev;
    },[])
  }
```

and in your view

```
<select id="categories" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Please select an item</option>
  <option
    *ngFor="let item of this.outputData; let i = index"
    value="{{ i }}"
    >{{ item }}</option
  >
</select>
```

**EDIT:** 
As you want to iterate through object inside array, you can use

```
 this.outputData = Object.keys(this.categoryObj).reduce((prev, curr) => {     
      prev.push(this.categoryObj[curr]);
      return prev;
    }, [])
```

this will give you array of objects

```
0: Object
name: "Candle"

1: Object
name: "Oil"
```

and you can bind it like this

```
<select id="categories" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Please select an item</option>
  <option
    *ngFor="let item of this.outputData; let i = index"
    value="{{ i }}"
    >{{ item.name }}</option
  >
</select>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dmahfz)

Comment: thanks for replying and Happy New year to you. I placed console.log("this.categoryObj[curr].name: ", this.categoryObj[curr].name); just underneath the prev.push and above the return, but nothing showed in the console and no items in the dropdown - is this because it is in a closure?

Comment: Also, when I used debugger; I received a warning - Use of debugger statements is forbidden

Comment: @kronus check my demo link you will understand how it works, secondly debugger is just for me you can remove it. and this will return the array you want to bind into select. and yes happy new year to you too

Comment: yeah, I was just going through that. As a result, I tried this.categoryObj["Categories"], which shows the following in the console and that is what I wanted - this.categoryObj:  
{…}
​
candles: Object { name: "Candle" }
​
chocolates: Object { name: "Chocolates" }
​
oils: Object { name: "Oil" }
​
toys: Object { name: "Toys" } - but, when I went to the component with the dropdown it crashed with not a specific error - ERROR Error: "[object Object]" core.js: 1673

Comment: @kronus check my edit, you have object inside object, you need to convert this object to array to make it iterate, try to understand my code and then implement it. also check demo for your output.

Comment: `this.output = Object.values(this.categoryObj);`

Answer (score 0):

Declare one variable to hold the revised JSON list:

```
list : any[] = [];
```

Just replace your get request with this:

```
this.http.get(this.jsonUriNestObj).subscribe(resultObj => {
    this.categoryObj = resultObj["Categories"];
    Object.keys(this.categoryObj).forEach(key => {
       this.list.push(this.categoryObj[key])
    })
});
```

HTML:

```
<select id="categories" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Please select an item</option>
  <option *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index" [value]="i">
      {{ item.name }}
  </option>
</select>
```

[`FORKED STACKBLITZ`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1fgi8i)